# .htaccess Escaping Periods

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I recently had an RFI attack where the query string had a bunch of ../../../ and I'd like to modify .htaccess to prevent any ../ in the query string.

I was trying this until I realized the period needed to be escaped:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ../
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

I then changed it to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\./
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

But it still forbids any / in the query string.

Also, If I have the rule in `{REQUEST_URI}` would that make the `{QUERY_STRING}` redundant?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have had success getting this to work by:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\.\./)
```

However, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.\./` or `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\./)` does not.  I've also tried `/\.\./` & `(/\.\./)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%{QUERY_STRING}` is everything after the **?**, so your rules successfully block a URL like htis:

```
http://domain.com/blah.php?../../../path
```

But your URI won't be checked. You can check against both by amending your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\./ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.\./ 
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

Comment: Would `{REQUEST_URI}` include everthing after `{HTTP_HOST}` and before `{QUERY_STRING}` ?  `http://mysite/../` just takes me to `http://mysite`.  Doesn't show forbidden.

Comment: @Go3Team Yes, in the above example, `%{REQUEST_URI}` would be `/blah.php`

Comment: @Go3Team additionally you could replace both those conditions with just: `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.\./` and that would cover both the URI and query strings